# How to deploy remotely WAR to JBoss 5.1.0.GA using Cargo maven plugin?

Tags: deployment, jboss, maven-cargo

I am trying to deploy remotely a WAR file to JBoss 5.0.1 GA using Cargo maven plugin but it seems that I can't.
I have found similar threads but none of them finally helped me to solve my problem.
I follow these [instructions](http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer#JBossRemoteDeployer-jboss5x6x). Some points that seem to be important are:

> *As of CARGO 1.0.3, the way CARGO supports remote deployments on the JBoss Application Server has drastically evolved. Starting from JBoss 5.x, JBoss has a Deployment Manager that can be used for deploying things on the JBoss server.*

My pom file looks like this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>true</wait>
                <container>
                    <timeout>500000</timeout>
                    <containerId>jboss51x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.remote.username></cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password></cargo.remote.password>
                         <cargo.hostname>localhost</cargo.hostname>
                         <cargo.rmi.port>8080</cargo.rmi.port>
                         <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1512m</cargo.jvmargs>  
                    </properties>
                    <deployables>
                      <deployable>
                        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                      </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
             <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.jboss.integration</groupId>
                      <artifactId>jboss-profileservice-spi</artifactId>
                      <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
                     <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
                     <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
                     <type>pom</type>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

When I try to deploy my war (by running mvn cargo:deploy) I am getting this kind of errors:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:8080 and discovery failed with error: javax.na
ming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.Comm
unicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1763)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:693)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.getDeploymentManager(JBossDeployer.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.tools.jboss.JBossDeployer.deploy(JBossDeployer.java:70)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.deploy(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:212)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]

javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:8080 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException:Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Rootexception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]]
```

Do you have any suggestions? It is not even clear to me if I need to install some special plugins or libraries in my JBoss or my pom configuration should be enough to remotely deploy my war file. Probably I am missing something fundamental here.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :)

I used wrong rmi port. The default one is 1099.
So, I put in my pom file this `<cargo.rmi.port>1099</cargo.rmi.port>` and problem fixed!