# Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I have two projects The first is Ejb3 project the name is SessionBean and the java project, is SessionBeanClient. For IDE i use eclipse indigo. I have finish the code and when i compiled i get an  error. Here is the error;

```
Feb 26, 2012 5:01:32 PM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1537)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1084)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410011: IOException received when reading from connection SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl[ java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:53584 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] ESTABLISHED true true]  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1481)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: End-of-stream
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1700)
    ... 4 more
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'SessionFacade1#com.iqbal.interfaces.ISessionFacade1Local' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=8080, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=8080, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.iqbal.client.BeanClient.main(BeanClient.java:36)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=8080, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.connectionAbort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1537)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1084)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410011: IOException received when reading from connection SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl[ java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:53584 remote=localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] ESTABLISHED true true]  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.ioexceptionWhenReadingConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doOptimizedReadStrategy(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1481)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: End-of-stream
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.nonBlockingRead(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1700)
    ... 4 more
```

For interface

```
enter code here
package com.iqbal.interfaces;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface ISessionFacade1Local 
{
    public double generatedRandomNumber(int number);
}
```

For Session Bean

```
enter code here

package com.iqbal.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import com.iqbal.interfaces.ISessionFacade1Local;

@Stateless(name="SessionFacade1", mappedName="SessionFacade1")
public class SessionFacade1 implements ISessionFacade1Local
{

    @Override
    public double generatedRandomNumber(int number) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Math.random();
    }

}
```

And For the client

```
enter code here
package com.iqbal.client;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.iqbal.interfaces.ISessionFacade1Local;


public class BeanClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          Properties props = new Properties();

          props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                            "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

          props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                            "com.sun.enterprise.naming");

          props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                            "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");


          // optional.  Defaults to localhost.  Only needed if web server is running
          // on a different host than the appserver   
          props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

          // optional.  Defaults to 3700.  Only needed if target orb port is not 3700.
          props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "8080");

          try 
          {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
            ISessionFacade1Local local = (ISessionFacade1Local)ic.lookup("SessionFacade1#com.iqbal.interfaces.ISessionFacade1Local");

            System.out.println("Random Number is== "+local.generatedRandomNumber(200));
          } 
          catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I already add SessionBean project to SessionBeanClient from build path and have adding appserv-rt.jar and gf-client.jar and glassfish server library. But.. the error above still come out. Anyone can help, Please...?

Answer (score 1):

i already get the answer it is just change the port 8080 to 3700. Why?, because the 8080 for local, and because i set @Remote in the interface so i have to used 3700. Try it and if any something wrong, tell me.

Comment: Port 8080 is Glassfish's default port HTTP (Web sites, web services). Port 3700 is the default port for the Corba ORB (over the IIOP protocol), which is the used to call remote EJBs.

Answer (score 0):

I had these days a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436558/how-to-deploy-remotely-war-to-jboss-5-1-0-ga-using-cargo-maven-plugin/9465702#9465702) (at least I think is relevant).
After some investigation I realized that I was using wrong RMI port in my configurations. I used 8080 but in my case it seemed that it wasn't clear that servlet port (8080) is not the same with RMI port (in my case in JBoss 1099 which is the default one).